# Using a thesis template: Listing my publications by referencing a .bib file

Tags: bibtex, bibentry

I'm relatively new to Latex and new to Stack exchange.

I am using the `ucthesis` template (University of California) on ShareLatex.com and am currently filling out a CV within the thesis document.

I am having trouble getting my publications to list at the end of my CV. I have a file called `my_pubs.bib` containing my publications in typical latex form.

The hints I have found online are based on writing a CV as its own separate document, as opposed to a CV within a global ucthesis template. I think this may be a cause of my confusion.

In my case so far, I have used the command in a root file called `dissertation.tex`:

```
\usepackage{bibentry}
```

so that in my `vitae.tex` file I use:

```
\nobibliography{my_pubs}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{vitaesection}{Selected Publications}
\begin{itemize}
\item [2013] \bibentry{lee2013modeling}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\end{itemize}
\end{vitaesection}
}
\end{vitae}
```

When I compile, I don't see the reference cited. Other parts of the CV have a similar itemized form that compiles without a hitch.

Any ideas as to what might be going wrong? Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you provide us with a link to the template?

Comment: Where is `vitaesection` defined? And there is a 'stray' `}` character just before `\end{vitae}`.

Comment: Hi, Werner. Here is where the files can be found: 
http://www.movesinstitute.org/~kolsch/ucthesis/

Comment: Hi @Christian Hupfer, thanks for reformatting my post to conform with the conventions of this site.

the vitasection is defined in the ucthesis.clo file from the link listed above. 

The 'stray' } I don't think is actually stray. I neglected to give you big picture of vitae.tex, which is also found in the link in my above comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to read my post and being so eager to help.

Comment: If you are using Texmaker then I think the following link has a simple solution. http://deparkes.co.uk/2015/06/30/latex-thesis-publications-list/

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the references with a \nocite{} command.  That is, if you want a reference with a tag "mythesis" to appear, use the \nocite{mythesis} in your document, and the thesis will appear in the bibliography without having to be referenced in the main text.

The relevant section would look like this

```
 \renewcommand{\bibname}{My Publications}
 \begin{document}
 \nocite{mypaper}

 \begin{thebibliograpy}
 \end{thebibliography}
 \end{document}
```

https://texfaq.org/FAQ-fixnam     on how to change fixed names/

Comment: Thank you for you reply, Wendy. However, it seems that my initial question was misunderstood: I do not want a bibliography per se, but rather a list of publications in section of my CV. But you are correct in that I am not citing any of those references anywhere in my CV.

Comment: Could you not modify the bibleography style in the c.v.

Comment: I am able to change anything but since I am new to latex, I an hesitant to mess with commands that I do not fully understand. As of now, I am trying to understand why the reference does not show up in my CV.

Comment: If you redefine the bibliography style in your c.v. then you could turn it into a a list of books in bibliography style.  The change would only affect your c.v., and not other documents you might make from the list.

Comment: A bit of google found your answer.  I modified my post with the relevant clue.

Comment: Thanks, @wendy.krieger but I am still not sure about how that could assist me in getting the results I want. Could you please explain? I'm not too familiar with Latex.

Comment: I put something like what's needed in my answer